# How to use list comprehension or apply(instead of iterrows) for iterating dataframes pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, iteration, apply

I have below code iterating over dataframes based on a primary key to compare each cell value.
This code is for comparsion of two datasets. Trying to compare each and every cell using a PK iterating over dataframes. Looking for a fast and efficient option as iterrows() is very slow.

*Assume a= df with 1000 rows, this is source data &   b=df with 1000 rows, this is target data*
difference = df that will store mismatched cell values with column name and primary key

```
for i in df123['ColumnName'].unique().tolist():
        for index, row in a.iterrows():
            for ind, rw in b.iterrows():
                if row[i] != rw[i]:
                    l = [primary_key, i, row[i], rw[i]]
                    difference.loc[len(difference), :] = l

difference.to_csv("report.csv")
```

I know iterrow() is inefficient and is very slow hence trying to see how can i replace it with apply() or list comprehension in above code having for loops.

Sample dataframes
a = source dataframe

| tick_id | value | id_mkt | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1404567 | apple | zer1wsed | 20200106 | 12.34 |
| 3409809 | orange | djhnf98y | 20200106 | 42.09 |

b = target dataframe

| tick_id | value | id_mkt | date | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1404567 | apple | qwe8762q | 20200106 | 12.40 |
| 3409809 | orange | poi543yu | 20200106 | 41.00 |
| 3409809 | orange | djhnf98y | 20200106 | 42.09 |
| 1404567 | apple | zer1wsed | 20200106 | 12.34 |

*difference* Dataframe is expected output has key, column name having mismatches and mismatched values present in source & target.
Expected output as below,  (EX: shown only 1 row of difference)

| primary_key | col_name | source_a | target_b |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1404567 | id_mkt | djhnf98y | poi543yu |

Comment: It would be really helpful if you post sample dataframes withexpected output

Comment: @AnuragDabas check example df's

Comment: Not sure how you derive the difference df from supplied input?  tick_id in source_a = 1404567 has id_mrkt = zer1wsed, Target_b has two rows where tick_id = 1404567 the first has id_mkt = qwe8762q and the second has id_mkt = zer1wsed.  So how do you produce the desired output?